# Input problems in cmd

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, input, cmd

I'm having a problem where if I run my python program in the windows terminal, text with inserted variables (`%s`) have wacky results, where as in the python shell it works fine.

Code:

```
print("Hi! What's your name?")
name = input("name: ")
print("Nice to meet you %s" % name)
print("%s is a good name." % name)
print("This line is only to test %s in the middle of the text." % name)
input("press enter to exit")
```

Result in python shell:

[image: Python Shell Result]

Result in cmd:

[image: cmd result]

I'm using Windows 10 and python32 in case you needed to know.

Comment: That is interesting, could you please use `format` instead of `%` and post the results please ?

Comment: Works fine for me on Win8.1.  I ran it from a Windows command line and the output looks just like your Python shell result.

Comment: Works for me under windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the original 3.2.0 on Windows.  The `input()` statement stripped off the "\n" but not the '\r', so the string input is hidden.

See https://bugs.python.org/issue11272

Quick fix:

```
name = input("name: ").rstrip()
```

It was fixed in 3.2.1.  You really should upgrade your Python!